# Python - Could some explain this Code roughly to me?

Tags: python, ascii

I was on StackExchange and saw this code for ASCII space invaders, and want to try and understand the concepts behind it. If anyone has a few minutes to point out the key concepts to someone who started only a few weeks ago, it would be much appreciated!

```
    exec'''import threading as t
    import msvcrt,Queue,time,random,os
    u=raw_input('name:')
    r=range
    @Z:
    $~(S):S.w=78;S.h=30;S.X();S.l='';S.Q=[];S.q=[];S.m=''
    $J(S,x,y,c):S.q.append([x,y,c])
    $X(S):S.s=[[' '^y in r(78)]^x in r(30)]
    $V(S):
    ?s='';S.X()
    ?^x,y,z in S.q:S.s[y][x]=z
    ?S.q=[]
    ?^x in S.s:
    ? ^y in x:s+=y
    ? s+='\\n'
    ?s+=S.m.center(S.w)
    ?if s!=S.l:os.system('cls');S.l=s;print s
    @E(Exception):pass
    @C:
    $~(S,g,c,p):S.g=g;S.c=c;S.p=p;S.s=[]
    $M(S,a,d):
    ?if (a<0 and S.p[d]==0) or (a>0 and S.p[d]==(S.g.z.h if d else S.g.z.w)-1):raise        
    E()
    ?S.p[d]+=a
    $X(S):S.s.remove(S)
    @A(C):
    $~(S,g):C.~(S,g,'A',[39,28])
    $M(S,a,d=0):
    ?try:C.M(S,a,d)
    ?except E:pass
    @Y(A):
    $~(S,g,p):C.~(S,g,'Y',p);S.s=g.a
    @B(C):
    $~(S,g,p,n):C.~(S,g,'|'if n<0 else'*',[p[0],p[1]+n]);S.s=g.b;S.d=n;S.a=0 if n<0         
    else 1
    $M(S):
    ?try:C.M(S,S.d,1)
    ?except E:S.X()
    $b(S):S.g.z.J(S.p[0],S.p[1],'X');S.g.z.V();S.X()
    $co(S):
    ?^w in S.g.w:
    ? if S.p==w.p:S.b();w.X()
    ?if S.a:
    ? if S.p==S.g.p.p:S.b();S.g.d()
    ?else:
    ? ^a in S.g.a:
    ??if S.p==a.p:S.b();S.g.P(50);a.X()
    @W(C):
    $~(S,g,p):C.~(S,g,'#',p);S.s=g.w
    @I(t.Thread):
    $~(S,g):t.Thread.~(S);S.f=1;S.c={'a':g._g4,'d':g._g3,'x':g._X,' ':g._fi};S.start()
    $run(S):
    ?while S.f:
    ? c=msvcrt.getch()
    ? if c in S.c:S.c[c]()
    $X(S):S.f=0
    @G:
    $~(S):S.z=Z();S.x=3.0;S.c=0;S.b=[];S.Q=Queue.Queue();S.I=I(S);S.g2=0;S.g1=0;S.do=0;S.f=1;S.v=0;S.l=3;S.ti=[];S.G(1);S.O()
    $O(S):
    ?while S.f:
    ? time.sleep(0.02)
    ? if not S.a:S.G(1)
    ? S.ch();S.B();S.u()
    $u(S):
    ?S.z.X();S.P(0)
    ?s=u+' '+`S.l`
    ?^i in r(len(s)):S.z.J(i,0,s[i])
    ?^i in S.a+S.b+[S.p]+S.w:S.z.J(i.p[0],i.p[1],i.c)
    ?S.z.V()
    $ch(S):
    ?try:
    ? while not S.Q.empty():S.Q.get_nowait()();S.Q.task_done()
    ?except Queue.Empty:pass
    $cl(S):
    ?try:
    ? while not S.Q.empty():S.Q.get_nowait();S.Q.task_done()
    ?except Queue.Empty:pass
    $_g4(S):
    ?if not S.g2:S.g2=1;S.Q.put(S.g4)
    $g4(S):S.p.M(-1);S.g2=0
    $_g3(S):
    ?if not S.g1:S.g1=1;S.Q.put(S.g3)
    $g3(S):S.p.M(1);S.g1=0
    $_X(S):S.I.X();S.Q.put(S.X)
    $X(S):S.f=0;S.I.X();S.st()
    $_fi(S):
    ?if not S.do:S.do=1;S.Q.put(S.fi)
    $fi(S):S.b.append(B(S,S.p.p[:],-1));S.do=0;S.P(-1)
    $_af(S):S.Q.put(S.af)
    $af(S):c=random.choice(S.a);S.b.append(B(S,c.p[:],1));S.nt(random.uniform(0.1,2),S._af)
    $nt(S,n,f):x=t.Timer(n,f);S.ti.append(x);x.start()
    $st(S):
    ?^i in S.ti:i.cancel()
    $G(S,n=0):
    ?S.st();S.cl();S.p=A(S);S.a=[];S.w=[];S.b=[]
    ?^x in[[i,o]^i in r(30)^o in r(3,10)]:
    ? if random.randint(0,99)%4==0:S.a.append(Y(S,x))
    ?S._m();S._af();f=[]
    ?^x in [6,27,46,65]:f+=[[z,y]^z in r(x,x+6)^y in r(23,26)]
    ?^i in f:S.w.append(W(S,i))
    ?S.v+=n;S.z.m='Level %s'%S.v;S.u()
    ?if S.x>0.2:S.x=1.6 - S.v*0.1
    ?S.m1=0;S.m2=0;S.k=1;time.sleep(3)
    $_m(S):S.Q.put(S.m)
    $m(S):
    ?x=0
    ?if S.m2:S.m2=0;S.m1=0;S.k=-S.k;x=1
    ?^i in S.a:i.M(*(abs(S.k),1)if x else(S.k,0))
    ?if S.m1==47:S.m2=1
    ?else:S.m1+=1
    ?S.nt(S.x,S._m)
    $B(S):
    ?^i in S.b:i.M();i.co()
    $d(S):
    ?S.l-=1
    ?if S.l==0:S.z.m='Game Over!';S.X();return
    ?S.G(0)
    $P(S,n):
    ?S.c+=n if S.c+n>0 else 0;x=`S.c`
    ?^n in r(len(x)):S.z.J(n,1,x[n])
    G()'''.replace('@','class ').replace('?','  ').replace('$',' def ').replace('^','for ').replace('~','__init__')
```

I am not saying I am going to be coding anything like this, but just want to get an idea of what the heck is going on! :)

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

This code is deliberately obfuscated. To make it clearer, try to do the replacements mentioned in the last line (`@ -> class`, etc.).

Then you'll get something like:

```
import threading as t
import msvcrt,Queue,time,random,os
u=raw_input('name:')
r=range
class Z:
     def __init__(S):S.w=78;S.h=30;S.X();S.l='';S.Q=[];S.q=[];S.m=''
     def J(S,x,y,c):S.q.append([x,y,c])
     def X(S):S.s=[[' 'for y in r(78)]for x in r(30)]
     def V(S):
        ...
```

This is still quite contracted, but much more readable.
However, I'd recommend to make sure you are familiar with all common constructs of the language before solving riddles like this one.

Comment: Ah okay, It was on the Code Golf page, so that would explain the obfuscation :) Thanks for the help. I'll heed your advice and put it into the "fridge" until I'm ready.

Answer (score 1):

It's some sort of minify, to compress as much code into as little space as possible, without relaying on true compression-algorithm.

Basically it's some sort of a text-console space invaders mini-game, which uses threads, queue ascii-art and msvcrt for keyboard-input to play.